# How can I make an interactive Label with Tkinter in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make an idlegame using Tkinter, but I don't know how to keep the Label that shows the amount of money updating.

I tried to make the label update using a while loop but the program didn't load the window without a mainloop() properly.
I've put w.mainloop() in the loop, but now it doesn't repeat anymore. (w=Tk())

```py
def money():
    File=open('./assets/save/money.txt','r')
    moneynow=File.read()
    File.close()
    try:
        if int(moneynow) >> 0 or int(moneynow) == 0:
            do='nothing'
    except:
        File=open('./assets/save/money.txt','w')
        File.write('0')
        File.close()
        w.destroy()

text1=Label(w,text='You currently have',bg='#CEE3F6',font=('arial black',10),fg='#820038')
text1.place(x=250,y=5)
text2=Label(w,text='$',bg='#CEE3F6',font=('arial black',10),fg='#820038')
text2.place(x=298,y=70)


#Interactive GUI
while True:
    money()
    File=open('./assets/save/money.txt','r')
    moneyamount=File.read()
    File.close()
    moneydisplay=Label(w,text=moneyamount,bg='#CEE3F6',font=('impact',40),fg='#FFCA4F',pady=-3)
    moneydisplay.place(x=289,y=25,height=45)
    w.mainloop()
```

Expected result: The loop keeps continuing.

Actual result: The loop doesn't repeat itself, since the compiler stops after w.mainloop().

Comment: mainloop - is a loop and it runs all time till you close window. You can use `w.after(time_in_ms, function_name) to run `function_name()` after `time_in_ms` milliseconds and it can update label and run `after(...) ` again

Comment: `>>` is bit operation, not comparition. You need `>=` instead of `>` and `==`

Comment: For your case, the simple way is to change `w.mainloop()` to `w.update_idletasks()`.  The other suggestion is to create `moneydisplay` once in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

`mainloop` is loop which run all time till you close window. You have to use `after(time, function_name)` to send it to `mainloop` and it will run it after selecte time - this way it will repeate function like in own loop.

```
from tkinter import *

def update_money():
    with open('./assets/save/money.txt') as f:
        moneynow = f.read()

    try:
        if int(moneynow) < 0:
            with open('./assets/save/money.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write('0')
        w.destroy()
    except:
        print('Cant convert')
        w.destroy()


    moneydisplay['text'] = moneynowe    
    w.after(1000, update_money) # run again after 1000ms (1s)

# --- main --  

w = Tk()

text1 = Label(w, text='You currently have')
text1.pack()

text2 = Label(w, text='$')
text2.pack()

moneydisplay = Label(w, text="") # empty label, I will put text later
moneydisplay.pack()

update_money() # put text first time

w.mainloop()
```